# How to Update a database column after changes from front end ASP.NET Mvc? Create a CheckBox and make it READONLY?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, readonly

I have created an application for several stores to fill in a questionnaire, the application has several tables within the database. Two of them are the ones  I am focusing on which are Audit and Storequestions. The Audit table contains the data for the stores for example: storename, and its primary key is “AuditId”. The storesquestion table contains all the questionnaire table and AuditId as a foreign key form the Audit table. 
I am wanting to create a Read Only tick box as an indication in order to find out which stores has completed the questionnaire as the only way I know which has completed the questionnaire is by looking in the database. My approach to re4solve this matter was to create a new column called read only within the Audit table with a Boolean datatype so when a store has completed the questionnaire it will set the read only row to 1(true). 
Could do with a bit of Help as I don’t seem to go forward at the moment

Thanks in advance

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        StoreQuestions sq = new StoreQuestions();
        sq.AuditId = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AuditId"];


        return View(sq);
    }

    //
    // POST: /StoreQuestions/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(StoreQuestions storequestions)  
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.StoreQuestions.Add(storequestions);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Audit", new { id = storequestions.AuditId });
        }

        return View(storequestions);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
  public class MainModel
{
    public StoreAudit StoreAudit { get; set; }
    public StoreQuestions StoreQuestion { get; set; }
    public List<StoreAudit> StoreAuditList { get; set; }
    public List<StoreQuestions> StoreQuestionsList { get; set; }
    public List<User> User { get; set; }
    public List<string> StoreWindow { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: You *could* create a ViewModel for this.. but that has a disadvantage.  If you want to **save** the property `readonly`  then you will have to create the column in the database, which would make your searching to see what stores did the questionairre much easier since you will be only looking for a `1` in that row.. have you tried your idea?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid i have already created the column but do not know how to move forward do you have any idea?

Comment: Okay, in your solution explorer do you have your .edmx where your database is located?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid the database is located in web.config within the connection string

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid also update my post with my view model

Comment: In your models folder, in the solution explorer, do you see a file with an extension of .edmx?

Comment: You need to update your model from the database is what I am trying to get to

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid no i dont see any i create the new column through the model using code first migration which auomatically update the database so it matches the model

Comment: Then that is what you should do

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid i have done this already what i need is help with the controller in order to grab the audit it and set the new column to true(1)

Comment: ohhhh I see.  so before the line `db.StoreQuestions.Add(storequestions);` put `storequestions.readonly = true;`

Comment: Or I mean you could just give the readonly property a default value of `1` in your database.. that way when a record is created, the readonly property will automatically be initialized as 1

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid the read only column is located within the Audit table not within the storequestions table, do i have to remove the read only column and move to the storequestions table?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid would you write a code example of what you suggesting if you dont mind

Comment: so if the readonly column is located within the Audit table, why did you post your Create action for the Storequestions table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I understand what you're trying to do.  In order to update the `readonly` property to `true` you have to find the audit record and then change the value of that record's `readonly` property.

Like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(StoreQuestions storequestions)  
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Audit findingAudit = db.AuditTable.Find(storequestions.AuditId);
            // db being your connectionstring property
            findingAudit.readonly = true;
            db.StoreQuestions.Add(storequestions);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Audit", new { id = storequestions.AuditId });
        }

        return View(storequestions);
    }
```

I hope this helps!